# How can I access information from Schoology's REST API in my Android app?

Tags: java, android, json, rest, oauth-2.0

I want to be able to access this JSON stuff from https://developers.schoology.com/api-documentation/rest-api-v1
inside my Android app. To do this, the user needs to login though Schoology inside my app (which I don't know how to implement). I think I might need to use https://developers.schoology.com/api-documentation/authentication but I'm not sure how OAuth is used in terms of Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this is a rather dated post but for anyone who visits this page in the future I've developed a very basic two-legged OAuth wrapper for Schoology:

https://github.com/rvanasa/schoology-api

This wasn't designed specifically for Android development, but to my understanding you'd be able to include the Maven module as part of your project dependencies.

Here's a quick example usage:

```
SchoologyRequestHandler schoology = new OAuthSchoologyRequestHandler(new BasicOAuthResourceLocator(DISTRICT_PREFIX), API_KEY, API_SECRET);

SchoologyResponseBody response = schoology.get("sections/123456789").requireSuccess().getBody();

System.out.println(response.getRawData()); // JSON string

SchoologyNode node = response.parse();
System.out.println(node.get("JSON_KEY").get(1).asString()); // index 1 of some JSON_KEY property
```